# After copying files using 'dd' to whole device (2tb hdd), can I 'dd' more files there without losing original files?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

Using external hdd's only - no internal hdd's...

I have a 2TB hdd that is .25% full; I 'dd' files to it using the following command:

```
"sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=16M of=/dev/sdb"

(sda and sdb = 2 different hdd's)

I would like to 'dd' more files there from another hdd, to fill up the rest of the 2TB hdd. I do **NOT** want to add the files to the 2TB hdd as an image.
```

```
**UPDATE:** 
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model:                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: xxxxx

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda2  264192 976771071 976506880 465.7G Microsoft basic data

:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Model:                 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2930522221 sectors (1.4 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   2          264192       976771071   465.6 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100118/discussion-on-question-by-topencrypt-after-copying-files-using-dd-to-whole-dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add files to the external hdd that **already** **had** ***files***, I used the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdx# bs=16M of=/dev/sdy#
```

First, I used gparted to create a 2nd partition to the hdd I was copying the files to, so as to **not** overwrite the files already there on the 1st partition.

Then, simply, I just included the partition numbers in the dd command for both "if" and "of".

The 2nd partition corresponds to the "#" in "sdy#" in the dd command above.

The partition "#" in "sdx#" corresponds to the partition of the host files' hdd.

Answer (score 0):

> can I add another partition and `dd` more files there without losing original files?

Yes (although "`dd` more files" is a weird term).

I assume in the output of `gdisk -l /dev/sda` `sda` is the target disk (that was `sdb` when you run the first `dd`).

You need to add a new entry to the partition table (with `fdisk`, `gdisk` or whatever alternative); a new partition that will start at the sector `976771072` (or a higher number, but I guess you don't want to waste space). The existing partition is with the number `2` (`sda2`), the most natural number for the new one will be `3` (`sda3`).

A procedure to add a partition in your case is no different than a general procedure to add a partition. In general some additional steps may be required to deal with "unfortunate" issues (e.g. Btrfs issues with cloned filesystems; or 512 vs 4096 logical sector size) but here it seems there are no such issues.

Just in case, make sure you're able to mount `/dev/sda2` and read files. Unmount before proceeding (again, just in case).

So create a new partition. I assume it will be `/dev/sda3`. Some programs may offer you to create a filesystem there. We may or may not need to explicitly create a filesystem; this depends on what you want to do next and my answer will cover this anyway. It's best to assign a type/code/UUID in advance that corresponds to the filesystem you want to put/create in the partition.

Then there are two separate ways, one with `dd` and one with files (this is why I said "`dd` more files" is a "weird term"):

- You can copy some old partition to the new partition with `dd`. The command will be like

  ```
  dd if=/dev/sdX1 of=/dev/sda3 bs=16M
  ```

  Notes:

  - `/dev/sdX1` should not be mounted with write access; `/dev/sda3` should not be mounted at all.
  - `/dev/sda3` must be at least as big as the filesystem inside `/dev/sdX1` (so you need to plan ahead when creating `/dev/sda3`). In practice a filesystem is almost never smaller than its partition, so we can rephrase as "`/dev/sda3` must be at least as big as `/dev/sdX1`". This has nothing to do with used space in terms of `df`; a filesystem may be only 1% full and it still takes its whole partition.
  - I used `/dev/sdX1`, not `/dev/sdX`. You want to copy partition to partition. The exception would be if `/dev/sdX` was a superfloppy (a filesystem on the entire device, without partition table; rare).
  - Instead of `/dev/sdX1` you can use `some_regular_file` that is an image of the filesystem you want to put in the new partition. "Of the filesystem", i.e. (basically) "of the partition", not "of the entire device with MBR, partition table and such".
  - In this case `dd` does nothing with files in the filesystem being copied.
- Or you can create a new filesystem and just copy the files. Use `mkfs` (or `mkfs.whatever`) to create a filesystem of the desired type inside `/dev/sda3` (unless the partitioning tool has already done it and you're OK with the result). Then mount the source and target filesystems and `cp` (`rsync`, `mc`, whatever) the files.

  Notes:

  - The new filesystem inside `/dev/sda3` must be big enough to hold the files (so you need to plan ahead when creating `/dev/sda3`). Compared to the above method (with `dd`) you are not bound by the size of the source filesystem, but by the total size of files. Keep in mind metadata also takes space and there's always some overhead.
  - `dd` has nothing to do here. Yes, you can technically use it to copy one file, but this is not what you want to do. You want `cp -r` or equivalent.

---

In general in a similar case instead of creating `/dev/sda3` one can enlarge `/dev/sda2`. Because you explicitly asked about "adding another partition", I understand "adding" is what you want.